# Sentence construction usage

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

"***The new generation will grow up believing that the kind of language they see on tv and social media is how arguments should be framed***." Now my question in which way "***is how arguments should be framed***" is used?

Comment: It's a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) functioning as complement of "be".

Comment: @BillJ  what is the subject of "is how arguments should be framed" of "is" in the sentence

Comment: [The kind of language] is [how arguments should be framed] - that is, the correct way to express arguments.

Comment: The subject of "how arguments should be framed" is "arguments". Some people would see it as a 'fused' relative construction meaning "the way that arguments should be framed", but this is only marginally acceptable.

Comment: Thanks to both of you @kate Bunting and BillJ